# What is meant to be passed in for the React Router <Router> history prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router (version 4.0.0) and the `Router` component has a required prop named "history".

I know in previous versions of react-router you could import `browserHistory` or `hashHistory` from the package and pass that along as the `history` prop to `<Router>` but in v4 neither of those are available.

The documentation available for the project makes no mention of what do to about this required history prop [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) and [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/Introduction.md) it references the `hashHistory` export that is no longer available in v4 of the package.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use  component with history you should import
browserHistory or hashHistory from 'react-router

```
import { Router,browserHistory } from 'react-router';
<Router history={browserHistory} routes={...} />
or
import { Router,hashHistory } from 'react-router';
<Router history={hashHistory} routes={...} />
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/v3/docs

Comment: Thanks, but my question was specifically about react-router v4, this solution only works for v2. Also, I already answered this :)

Answer (score 0):

I was importing `{ Router } from 'react-router-dom'` which does in fact have a required prop `history` but I needed to be importing `{ BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'` which does not have a required prop history. That cleared up the issue for me.